# Install Script is not running in my magento module?

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I am developing a magento module in which i am trying to install a table in database throught my script but for some reasons i am unable to run this install script.

Here's my `config.xml` code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<!-- turn on our module, required for install support -->
<modules>
<Gwb_Magecrmsync>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</Gwb_Magecrmsync>
</modules>
<frontend>
<routers>
    <magecrmsync>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
            <module>Gwb_Magecrmsync</module>
            <frontName>magecrmsync</frontName>
        </args>
    </magecrmsync>
</routers>
<layout>
    <updates>
        <magecrmsync>
            <file>adminhtml.xml</file>
        </magecrmsync>
    </updates>
</layout>
</frontend>
<admin>
<routers>
    <magecrmsync>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
            <module>Gwb_Magecrmsync</module>
            <frontName>magecrmsync</frontName>
        </args>
    </magecrmsync>
</routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
<menu>
    <menu1 translate="title" module="magecrmsync">
        <title>Synchronize</title>
        <sort_order>999</sort_order>
        <children>
            <menuitem1 module="magecrmsync">
                <title>Customers</title>
                <action>magecrmsync/adminhtml_customers</action>
            </menuitem1>
            <menuitem2 module="magecrmsync">
                <title>Orders</title>
                <action>magecrmsync/adminhtml_orders</action>
            </menuitem2>
            <menuitem3 module="magecrmsync">
                <title>Products</title>
                <action>magecrmsync/adminhtml_products</action>
            </menuitem3>
        </children>
    </menu1>
</menu>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <menu1 translate="title" module="magecrmsync">
                    <title>Synchronize</title>
                    <sort_order>999</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <menuitem1>
                            <title>Customers</title>
                        </menuitem1>
                        <menuitem2>
                            <title>Orders</title>
                        </menuitem2>
                        <menuitem3>
                            <title>Products</title>
                        </menuitem3>
                    </children>
                </menu1>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
</adminhtml>
<global>
<!-- turn on models -->
<models>
    <magecrmsync>
        <class>Gwb_Magecrmsync_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>Magecrmsync_mysql4</resourceModel>
    </magecrmsync>
    <magecrmsync_mysql4>
        <class>Gwb_Magecrmsync_Model_Mysql4</class>
        <entities>
            <magecrmsync>
                <table>magecrmsync</table>
            </magecrmsync>
        </entities>
    </magecrmsync_mysql4>
</models>
<!-- turn on models -->

<!-- turn on database connections -->
<resources>
<!-- setup is needed for automatic installation -->
    <magecrmsync_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>Gwb_Magecrmsync</module>
        </setup>
        <connection>
            <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
    </magecrmsync_setup>
    <magecrmsync_write>
        <connection>
            <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
    </magecrmsync_write>
    <magecrmsync_read>
        <connection>
            <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
    </magecrmsync_read>
</resources>

<blocks>
    <magecrmsync>
        <class>Gwb_Magecrmsync_Block</class>
    </magecrmsync>
</blocks>

<helpers>
    <magecrmsync>
        <class>Gwb_Magecrmsync_Helper</class>
    </magecrmsync>
</helpers>

<layout>
    <magecrmsync>
        <file>adminhtml.xml</file>
    </magecrmsync>
</layout>

</global>
</config>
```

Here's my `mysql4-install-0.1.0.php` file which is under `Gwb/Magecrmsync/sql/magecrmsync_setup`

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('magecrmsync')};
CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('magecrmsync')} (
`user_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`username` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
`password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL),
PRIMARY KEY  (`user_id`) 
ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
");
$installer->endSetup();
```

Can anyone tell me that what am i doing wrong here which is not letting my install script to execute?

Any help would be appreciated and will be helpful to me.

Comment: Haven't checked your source, but a common pitfall is the following: check your `core_resource` table. Maybe your previous testing already created a `magecrmsync` entry with version 0.1.0. If so, Magento won't run your SQL script again, because it "thinks" your module is already up-to-date. In that case, just delete the proper entry in the `core_resource` table and try again.